# Is there any way to "overload" two macrodefs in ant?

Tags: ant, overloading, macrodef

I want to implement a `<macrodef/>` that can be called in two ways: With a single file parameter, or with a `<fileset/>`:

```
<macrodef name="sqlplus">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <sequential>
        <!-- there be dragons, here -->
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="sqlplus">
    <element name="files"/>
    <sequential>
        <for param="file">
            <path>
                <files/>
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <!-- call the other macro -->
                <sqlplus file="@{file}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there any trick I can use to implement "quasi"-overloading? Or do I have to rename one of the macrodefs? I know I could write this, and check if the arguments are set (e.g. using ant-contrib):

```
<macrodef name="sqlplus">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <element name="files" optional="yes"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</macrodef>
```

But there is no way to make an `<attribute/>` optional.

Comment: OT: Hi Lukas! Once, I was trying to hack Ant script to solve problem with adding manifest attribute into jar. I gave up any XML "programming" and [wrote it](http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2013/10/kdyz-java-neveri-svym-vlastnim-jarum.html#build_script) using Javascript and [scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html).

You don't need ant-contrib for Javascripting, only ant-nodeps. Maybe Javascript will provide nicer way to cope with absence of attribute or element.

Comment: @TomášZáluský: Yeah, I know things could be done with JavaScript. I'll probably just settle for two differently-named macrodefs. But I haven't found any answer to this problem, so I thought for the record, if a future visitor finds this question, they might find it useful...